# How do I get jQuery/AJAX result into table cell

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this script here that outputs a result from a sql db query but I can not figure out how to get it to put the result in the table cell specified.

Here is query:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.typeval').change(function(){
    var movement =  $(this).val();
    var client_id = $(this).parent().siblings().find('.clientval').val();
    var class_id = <? echo $class_id; ?>;

$.ajax({ 
  type: "POST",
  url: "movement_count.php",
  data: {movement:movement, client_id:client_id, class_id:class_id},
  dataType: "json", 
  success:(function(output) {

      $.each(output, function(index, value){
      alert(value);
      $(".count").append(output[value]);
      }) // each

   }) // success

  }); // ajax

  }); // .typeval

});  // document

</script>
```

I want to put the result of this (value):

```
alert(value);
```

into here:

```
<td><label class="count"></label></td>
```

The `<td>` I am targeting on the same row as the `<select>` menu that is triggering the result. There will also be multiple table rows with this exact same cell `<td>`. So I need to target  the `<td>` on this row only somehow. Can someone help me with this? Im not sure if I need the `$.each` but my php query is a `mysql_fetch_row` array even though the value returned will always be just one number.

Here is the HTML markup for the table cell I need the `value` in:

```
<td><label class="count"></label></td>
```

JS source code for `class=count`:

```
$(".count").append(output[index]);
```

**ITS WORKING!!!!** here is the code below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.typeval').change(function(){
    var movement    =  $(this).val();
    var client_id   = $(this).parent().siblings().find('.clientval').val();
    var class_id    = <? echo $class_id; ?>;
        $count      = $(this).parents('tr').find('label.count');

$.ajax({ 
  type: "POST",
  url: "movement_count.php",
  data: {movement:movement, client_id:client_id, class_id:class_id},
  dataType: "json", 
  success:(function(output) {

      $.each(output, function(index, value){
      //alert(value);
      $count.append(output[index]);
      }) // each

   }) // success

}); // ajax

}); // .typeval

});  // document
```

Comment: anyone else feel like taking a stab at it?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
$("label.count<?php echo $client_id; ?>").append(output[value]);
```

With

```
$("label.count<?php echo $client_id; ?>").append(value);
```

Or alternately with this

```
$("label.count<?php echo $client_id; ?>").append(output[index]);
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but it's not working. The response from the `POST` in firebug is correct but I can not seem to get it into the table cell.

Comment: what is the html mark up in view source for **$("label.count<?php echo $client_id; ?>")**?

Comment: @Colbyd, i need the html markup for js code. What its generating in view source for **$("label.count<?php echo $client_id; ?>")**

Comment: I changed the code a little since using the `php` variable was not working. I somehow need to target the `<td><label class="count">` on the same row as the `<select>` menu `.typeval` that is triggering the ajax `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

**Working code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.typeval').change(function(){
    var movement    =  $(this).val();
    var client_id   = $(this).parent().siblings().find('.clientval').val();
    var class_id    = <? echo $class_id; ?>;
        $count      = $(this).parents('tr').find('label.count');

 $.ajax({ 
  type: "POST",
  url: "movement_count.php",
  data: {movement:movement, client_id:client_id, class_id:class_id},
  dataType: "json", 
  success:(function(output) {

      $.each(output, function(index, value){
      //alert(value);
      $count.append(output[index]);
      }) // each

   }) // success

}); // ajax

}); // .typeval

});  // document
```